# Android password XML attribute - Deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

How do I mask editText now?

[image]

My inputType is number. How should I mask it now and at the same time restricting it to just number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `android:inputType="numberPassword"` for the EditText.

Comment: Thanks! Was about to answer this myself.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `android:inputType="number"` with `android:inputType="numberPassword"`

Delete `android:password="true"`

For explanations on each of the values `inputType` can have:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:inputType="numberPassword"` as your attribute

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `android:password="true"` with `android:inputType="textPassword"`.
There is a list given for `inputType` like `numberPassword`, `numberUri`, `Date` etc..
For more details check on developer.android.com.

Answer (score -1):

Replace it with the following attribute

```xml
android:inputType="textPassword"
```